# Outputing UTF-8 string on Mac OS's Terminal

Tags: haskell, utf-8, macos, terminal

I got a programm in haskell outputting utf-8 using the package `utf8-string` and using only the output functions of this package.

I set the encoding of each file I write to this way :

```
hSetEncoding myFile utf8
{- myFile may be stdout -}
```

but when I try to output :

```
alpha = [toEnum 0x03B1] {- α -}
```

instead of the nice alpha letter I got on Linux (or in a file on windows), I got the following :

```
Î±
```

The weird thing is even if I try to write the output on a file, I can't read it back with mvim as an utf-8 file. Is there any way to get the correct behaviour

Comment: I think you mean __toEnum__ not __fromEnum__.

Comment: Using `utf8-string` in combination with the GHC native encoding stuff (setting the encoding of the handle) seems like it'd lead to double-escaping.

I've only ever used `utf8-string` on earlier GHCs, before there was supported for specifying the encoding of handles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tried this on GHC 6.12 just now. The new encoding feature eliminates the need
for `utf8-string` in this simple case.

```
import System.IO

main                         =  do
  out alpha stdout

alpha                        =  [toEnum 0x03B1] {- α -}

out s handle                 =  do
  hSetEncoding handle utf8
  hPutStrLn handle s
```

Please let me know if this works for you on OS X. Please post full code next time -- it would have made it much easier for me to help you.

Comment: Effectively, removing utf8-string removed my problem, I wouldn't have guessed. Thanks for the idea :)

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two things you have to make sure:

- The Terminal encoding must be set to UTF8:

[alt text http://files.droplr.com.s3.amazonaws.com/files/35740123/15WO3z.Picture%2026.png](http://files.droplr.com.s3.amazonaws.com/files/35740123/15WO3z.Picture%2026.png)

- The file is indeed encoded in UTF8 (it should be if you observe the right result on Linux)

Comment: Which file do you mean -- the output file or the source file?

Comment: You have an output file? I thought the output was in the Terminal... The input file must be encoded in UTF8. But in your case, I suppose the problem lies in the Terminal's encoding.